# how to integrate javascript in iPhone application?

Tags: javascript, iphone

i am new in iphone application and i want to integrate the javascript so would you please give some information about how to implement javascript?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what exactly you mean by

> i want to integrate the javascript

You have full JS support inside UIWebView. You can inject your own JS code and communicate with the existing JS code.

Comment: i know that we can use and communicate with the existing JS code.but actually i don't know how to use that code can you give some example of this kind of integrated script.

Comment: There is a "stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString" method... You can find few very useful code samples here: http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/tag/uiwebview

Answer (score 0):

According to the policy set by Apple on applications for the iPhone, you can not use any interpreted language. Thus, Javascript is unfortunately out of the question.

This is stated in the iPhone SDK agreement.

> 3.3.2 — An Application may not itself install or launch other executable
>   code by any means, including without
>   limitation through the use of a
>   plug-in architecture, calling other
>   frameworks, other APIs or otherwise.
>   No interpreted code may be downloaded
>   or used in an Application except for
>   code that is interpreted and run by
>   Apple’s Documented APIs and built-in
>   interpreter(s).

Answer (score 0):

Continuing with what Michael Kessler said you can also use javascript embedded in a UIWebView to access native iPhone functionality via libraries such as phoneGap making your javascript more powerful than the normal safari variety.

http://phonegap.com/download

Includes a iPhone project that you can use as a basis for your javascript application.